# How to quickly find out which tests have been fixed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have inherited a quite rotten test suite with over 1000 tests, where several hundreds are failing. There are several people fixing the tests, and I would like to quickly see which tests have been fixed between test job runs.

Currently, I copy the lists of failed tests from two runs, sort and diff them. I hope there is a better way.

The only thing I could find that mentions a better possibility is [this old thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Test-Result-Display-Fixed-Tests-td623050.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Sonar (now SonarQube)? You can pipe test results over to Sonar and keep test history in a searchable format. We use PMD/Findbugs/etc and test results to red/yellow/green a job for further CI deployment, but use Sonar for trends and analysis.